# How to set up existing SSL certificate in tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, ssl-certificate, java-7

I have SSL certificates from Godaddy for my domain and I already have application running on my domain .

Now I want my second application to run on the sub domain .

My problem is setting up existing SSL certificates to tomcat 7 .

For various reasons I have set up SSL directly to tomcat instead putting it on a apache.

I have tried various docs all the docs starts from setting up keystore and CSR.

so Is it Possible set up existing SSL certificates to tomcat 7 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Import the certificate,
2. Export your key, certificate and ca-certificate into a PKCS12 bundle.
3. Import the PKCS12 file into the keystore.
4. Change /opt/tomcat/config/server.xml file to make use of these certificate.

For more detail, please follow [this instruction](https://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2017/02/ssl-certificate-setup-tomcat.html)